# Are laryngealization, low phasal tone and creaky voice all the same thing?

Tags: phonetics

I read somewhere that creaky voice is produced by drawing the tongue root closer to the larynx. And also that the third tone in Mandarin Chinese is also regarded to as the low tone or creaky tone.

So I was wondering if the three terms are referring to the same gesture?

Is fundamental frequency controlled by the larynx or the vocal folds?

Comment: The larynx and the vocal folds are the same thing - or, at least, the latter is the most important part of the former.

Comment: @GrahamH. thanks for the reply! However, I still don't understand how creaky voice is different from low tone